# PowerShell CloseHandle on EventWaitHandle

Tags: powershell, synchronization, handle, thread-synchronization, event-wait-handle

I have two PowerShell scripts. One of them has to wait at the other at one point. Here are the relevant parts:

WaitingScript.ps1:

```
$StopEventName = 'MyEvent'

function Wait-StopEvent {
    $EventResetModeManualReset = 1
    $StopEventObject = New-Object -TypeName System.Threading.EventWaitHandle -ArgumentList $false, $EventResetModeManualReset, $StopEventName
    $StopEventObject.WaitOne()
}
```

SignallingScript.ps1:

```
$StopEventName = 'MyEvent'

function Signal-StopEvent {
    $StopEventObject = [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle]::OpenExisting( $StopEventName )
    $StopEventObject.Set()
}
```

It works well, I'm just not sure if I should call something like CloseHandle, or Close on `$StopEventObject` in either script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - at least I don't see a reason why you should *not* close the handle - otherwise the resources used by the handle would not be released. See [WaitHandle.Close at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.close?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_WaitHandle_Close)

Comment: And should I close it in both `Wait-StopEvent` and `Signal-StopEvent`, or only in `Wait-StopEvent`, which created it? In WinAPI I would call on both sides, but the page you linked says, it will call Dispose. Is it alright if Dispose is called twice?